# How to make page content not slide up when virtual keyboard appears - Android / PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, slide

I have this line...
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
...in my AndroidManifest.xml to fix a problem where:
1. Virtual keyboard is opened
2. The page slides up
3. The virtual keyboard is closed
4. The page doesn't slide back down again <- PROBLEM

That new line in the AndroidManifest.xml has fixed the above problem, but given me a new one... Now the page content slide up/down as the keyboard appears/hides - which I don't want.

How can I make it so that the page content just stays where it is all the time, so the keyboard effectively slides over the content rather than pushing the content up?